# Can I link to specific pages on my website from a facebook game?

Tags: facebook

I am developing an educational game on Facebook (Facebook Canvas App) and I would like the game to include external links to my website where the players can read more about specific educational topics. Is it true that Facebook prohibits including external links in the game?

Thank you!

Comment: Was my answer useful to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

External links are perfectly acceptable. An example of this is integrated ads. The ads topic is covered in multiple sections of the [Facebook for Developers - Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/), especially section 8. In that section, it even mentions the part about promotions, contests, sweepstakes, etc. I have participated in some of those, and *all* of them have linked externally for additional entries.

In section 1.5, it states:

> In addition, don't require people to log into your app in order to access third party apps or sites that are not used in connection with the experience your app provides.

This alone implies that you can use sites that are used in connection with the experience your app provides.

Section 4.8 states:

> Don’t build an app whose primary purpose is to redirect people off of Facebook.

If you are using the app to educate, and you are providing *optional* external information, then I believe your use does not violate this section.

As I do not know the design of your particular app, I can't suggest how to make the external information appear to be more integrated. If you are already providing a decent amount of detail within the app, a "Read More" (or similar) function taking them to external site would seem acceptable, especially if the user knows they are being directed away from your app to an external site.

When in doubt, you can discuss the issue with members of the  [Facebook Developers Group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers). Some of them have been doing it quite a while and probably know even more.